# Why Is This Rendering Twice?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**What I Would Like To Know**

This `React Native` component is rendering twice.
I want to know why and if this is bad code.

```js
export default class Items extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      refreshing: false,
      items: [],
    };
  }

  fetchData = async () => {
    const querySnapshot = await Fire.shared.getItemsByGenres(1);
    const items = await Fire.shared.pushItems(querySnapshot);
    this.setState({ items });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  _onRefresh() {
    this.setState({ refreshing: true });
    this.fetchData().then(() => {
      this.setState({ refreshing: false });
    });
  }

  render() {

  console.log('fire');

    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content
          refreshControl={(
            <RefreshControl
              refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
              onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
            />
          )}
        >
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

`console.log();` outputs twice :(

Is there any better ways using RefreshControl？

I would appreciate it if you guys give me any advice!

Comment: 1st render is when Component initially mounts. Then once it's mounted you do a fetch in `componentDidMount` in `fetchData` you're setting the state causing the render to happen again.

Comment: Thanks! Now I kinda understand how render works in React Native.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this component is in a proper situation. the asynchronous function for getting data is in a separated function. you call it inside `componentDidMount` so in the first initializing it renders without data. When the asynchronous function gets the data triggers a `setState` function to make another render with data. So it is obvious you see twice the `console.log` and definitely, you have two renders.

Comment: I see. I was worried about if this is not good. Thank you so much!

Comment: Dear @Wes, Do not worry, this is a proper way, but if you wanna see an alternative way, read [this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html) of ReactJS docs. it is experimental.